# SWRevealViewController hiding navigationbar for my front view controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I have Reveal View controller which has rear and front view, rear view is my side menu, The problem is when i tap on menu items from side menu it shows the destination view controller but navigation bar is not showing. Please help me. I'm new on iOS.
Here is my storyboard picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoLRI.jpg

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    itemIndex = indexPath.row
    self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "webview", sender: nil)
}
```

Here is on Prepare function

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let progressWebViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? ProgressWebViewController else {
        return
    }

    switch itemIndex {
    case 1:
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "aboutus") as! AboutUsController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break

    case 2:
        loadURL(progressWebViewController: progressWebViewController ,url: "https://google.com", title: "Event Planning")

    case 3:
        loadURL(progressWebViewController: progressWebViewController ,url: "https://google.com", title: "NCC Checklist")

    default:
        print("Unknown segue \(itemIndex)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line:
`self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

When you present a viewController it has a modal behavior and has no `navigationController`

so if you need navigationController on that you should use `pushViewController` instead

like this : `self.navigationController.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)`